# Method changing the value of a list wrongly

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

So I wrote a test code (trying to teach myself how to make sorting algorithms), which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string Compile (List<int> array)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                output += item.ToString() + " ";
            }
            return output;
        }

        static List<int> InsertSort(List<int> listToSort)
        {
            List<int> deliverList = new List<int>();
            deliverList = listToSort;
            int j = 0;
            int iterator = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < deliverList.Count; i++)
            {
                j = i;
                while(j>0)
                {
                    if(deliverList[j] < deliverList[j-1])
                    {
                        int temp = deliverList[j - 1];
                        deliverList[j - 1] = deliverList[j];
                        deliverList[j] = temp;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Iteration #[" + iterator.ToString() + "]: " + Compile(deliverList));
                    iterator++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            return deliverList;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> unsorted = new List<int>();

            List<int> sorted = new List<int>();

            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                unsorted.Add(random.Next(0, 100));
            }

            sorted = InsertSort(unsorted);

            Console.WriteLine("Unsorted Array: " + Compile(unsorted));
            Console.WriteLine("Sorted Array: " + Compile(sorted));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, **when I use the InsertSort method on the "sorted" array, the "unsorted" array is also changed**, outputting the sorted array two times and not letting me see the unsorted one. **What exactly is happening here**?

PS: Compile is just a simple method that compiles a list into a string with the elements separated by spaces.

Comment: deliverList = listToSort; this line, you assign the right to the left, so essentially they refer to the same list.

Comment: Whereas your implementation works, you might want to study insertion sort a bit more closely. Your implementation is doing more work than it has to.

Comment: @JimMischel How would you rate this code? ( For a beginner, I mean)

Comment: The code works, which is the most important thing for a beginner. If you're interested in a detailed code review, then you should post a question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You have the code `deliverList = listToSort;` which makes `deliverList` reference the same list as `listToSort`. They become synonyms.

Instead you should write:

```
        List<int> deliverList = listToSort.ToList();
```

That will make a copy of the list - and now they will both be different.

Your code now would output:

```
Iteration #[0]: 52 88 93 69 35 21 63 47 2 17 
Iteration #[1]: 52 88 93 69 35 21 63 47 2 17 
...
Iteration #[43]: 2 17 21 35 47 52 63 69 88 93 
Iteration #[44]: 2 17 21 35 47 52 63 69 88 93 
Unsorted Array: 88 52 93 69 35 21 63 47 2 17 
Sorted Array: 2 17 21 35 47 52 63 69 88 93
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it! For a beginner like me, these kinds of little details can get really out of hand!

Answer (score -3):

you need to make a copy of the list

```
        List<int> deliverList = listToSort.Select(x=>x);
```

Comment: This won't compile.